# Resolution local video stream

Tags: webrtc

As I understand correctly we have video adapter that can change resolution.
How to get frame aspect ratio or resolution of outbound stream or inbound?
Browser somehow know resolution for decoder...so should be a solution for get this resolution in native webrtc or js browser side, but I can't find this info

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints Are you looking for this?

Comment: As far as I understand getCapabilities() and getSupportedConstraints()  return information about list of avaiable resolutions, but in current time webrtc encoder/adapter using one of them and send in to stream, but which one? In addition to this, there is a degradation algorithm of resolution because of cpu overload...and I don't know what exactly resolution in outbound/inbound stream is

Comment: For me it sound like super simple ability...resolution of outbound stream. Is it really impossible in webrtc?

Comment: if you have a local video element the resize event should trigger on it.

Comment: I have but it can't help me. The properites: document.querySelector('video').videoWidth);
document.querySelector('video').videoHeight
return 640:480 all the time, but I parsed the header of the frame on the c++ side and resolution different, but parsing header of h264 very bad solution i think
The reason of resolution changed is: degradation resolution because of cpu overload. Parsing header of 264 on the server side for now only one solution what I have found...

Comment: I'm looking for found a way on client side js outbound stream or server c++ side inbound stream...